# Non finitely generated graded ring of a divisor in dimension >2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I spent some time looking for an example of non finitely generate graded ring
$R=\oplus H^0(X,mD)$ where $D$ is a divisor on a variety $X$ of dimensison $>2$.
I know there are several such examples (e.g Zariski's), but they are all on surfaces.
I believe there must exist many examples. Do you know any?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a way of generating lots of examples:

Start with a variety $X$ with an effective cone which is *not* rational polyhedral (i.e., not finitely generated) and let $L_1,\ldots,L_r$ be a collection of line bundles on $X$ such that their span $\{L_1^{a_1}\otimes \cdots\otimes L_r^{a_r} | a_1,\ldots,a_r \ge 0\}\,\,$   includes the effective cone. For example, one could take $X$ to be the blow-up of projective space at sufficiently many points, or a K3 surface of maximal Picard number.

Now consider the variety $Y=\mathbb{P}(E)$ where $E=L_1\oplus \cdots \oplus L_r$ and the line bundle $O(1)$ on $Y$. We have for $n\geq 0$,
$$
H^0(Y,O(n))\cong H^0(X,Sym^n(E))=\bigoplus_{a_1+\ldots +a_r=n}H^0(X,L_1^{a_1}\otimes \cdots\otimes L_r^{a_r})
$$so that $R(Y,O(1))$ is isomorphic to the sum of all sections of all effective line bundles on $X$: this is usually called the Cox ring of $X$. When the effective cone of $X$ is non-rational polyhedral it is clear that this ring is infinitely generated, since it requires sections from all effective divisor classes.

It is usually a difficult problem in birational geometry to decide when a nef and big divisor is semiample, i.e., some multiple of $D$ is base-point free. A well-known theorem of Zariski says that if $X$ is normal and projective, then $D$ is semiample if and only if the section ring $R(X,D)$ is finitely generated. So this theorem gives a way of producing nef and big divisors which are not semiample. In particular, choosing $X$ such that the nef-big cone is not rational polyhedral, $L=O(1)$ is nef and big, but not semiample, since $R(Y,L)$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: Hi John, nice example, but I think that you need to be a little more specific on the choice of line bundles $L_1,\ldots,L_r$: if they happen to be semi-ample, then the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$ will be finitely generated. In your sum, only non-negative multiples of the lines bundles appear.  Presumably it suffices to choose the line bundles $L_1,\ldots,L_r$ so that the intersection of the non-negative span of them with the effective cone is not finitely generated (and there is no need for them to be independent or to span the whole Picard group).

Answer (score 9):

I give Siu's analytical method  to test that the ring $$R(X,L)=\bigoplus_{m=1}^\infty H^0(X,mL)$$  is not finitely generated

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold and the ring $R(X,L)=\bigoplus_{m=1}^\infty H^0(X,mL)$ is finitely generated and let $s^{(m)}_1, … , s^{(m)}_{q_m}\in H^0 (X,mL) $

be a basis over $\mathbb C$. Let

$$ \Phi =\sum_{m=1}^\infty \epsilon_m( ∑_{j=1}^{q_m} |s^{(m)}_j|^2)^{1/m} $$

where $\epsilon_m$ is some sequence of positive numbers decreasing fast enough to guarantee convergence of the series. Then all the Lelong numbers of the closed positive $(1,1)$-current $$T=\frac{\frak{\sqrt{-1}}}{2\pi}\partial\bar\partial \log Φ$$ are rational numbers.

So one of ways to find some examples is to show that the Lelong number of $T$ is not rational at some point,  hence the ring $R(X,L)=\bigoplus_{m=1}^\infty H^0(X,mL)$ is not finitely generated

Definition: Let
$W\subset \mathbb C^n$
be a domain, and $\Theta$ a positive current of degree $(q,q)$ on
$W$. For a point $p\in W$
one defines
$$\mathfrak v(\Theta,p,r)=\frac{1}{r^{2(n-q)}}\int_{|z-p|<r}\Theta(z)\wedge (dd^c|z|^2)^{n-q}$$
The
Lelong number
of $\Theta$ at
$p$
is defined as

$$\mathfrak v(\Theta,p)=\lim_{r \to 0}\mathfrak v(\Theta,p,r)$$

Let $\Theta$ be the curvature of singular hermitian metric $h=e^{-u}$, one has

$$\mathfrak v(\Theta,p)=\sup\{\lambda\geq 0: u\leq \lambda\log(|z-p|^2)+O(1)\}$$

Answer (score 4):

In Section 7 of [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2946531) the authors gave an example of a smooth 3-fold $X$ with a divisor $D$ such that:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{h^0(\mathcal O_X(nD))}{n^3} = 6+ \frac{2\sqrt 3}{9}$

I would love to here about more natural examples!

Comment: Since the canonical ring is finitely generated, the "most natural" candidate line bundle with such a property would be an anticanonical bundle.  Unfortunately, I cannot think of an example at the moment, though...

Comment: Dear damiano: thank you for your insight. When you think of such example, please give an answer. 

Answer (score 2):

In their paper "Monge-Ampère equations in big cohomology classes", Boucksom, Eyssidieux, Guedj and Zeriahi give an example (Ex 5.4 page 46 here : http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.3674)
of a nef and big line bundle over a smooth projective 3-fold which is not semi-ample.
More precisely, every positive current in its cohomology class has poles along some subvariety.

Furthermore, it is well-known (Lazarsfeld, PAG e.g) that a nef and big line bundle has a finitely generated sections ring iff it is semi-ample.

In one word, their construction consists in using the famous example of Serre (and studied by Demailly-Peternell-Schneider) of a flat rank 2 vector bundle $E$ on some elliptic curve $C$, and considering on $V:=\mathbb P(E\oplus A)$ (for $A$ ample on $C$) the tautological line bundle $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P(V)}(1)$.